# The given code in codesandbox is not working

Tags: react-redux, react-router

please provide solution for this

https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-data-routing-link-forked-g6ef2?file=/src/router/AppRouter.js

Answer (score 0):

You are using React Router v6. In v6, the `Link` component needs the state to be passed directly as prop instead of inside `to`. Like this

```
    <Link
      className="btn btn-primary"
      to={{
        pathname: "/details"
      }}
      state={state}
    >
      Register
    </Link>
```

Also you need to use the hook to get location in the `Details` component.

```
const location = useLocation();
```

See the docs for more details. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link

EDIT: Here is the updated code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-data-routing-link-forked-v2zctg?file=/src/components/Details.js:122-130

Comment: const location = useLocation(); where to use this in details component

Comment: Have edited the answer with the updated code

Comment: it is not working and showing undefined.please provide updated code in codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-data-routing-link-forked-v2zctg?file=/src/components/Details.js:122-130

Comment: thank you it is working in our code